# HPA NOT scale up on Custom Metrics after updating targetValue

Tags: prometheus, amazon-eks, hpa, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I have an AWS EKS cluster, and I have set up the Prometheus and the Prometheus-Adapter.
The thing is, I have tried different values for my HPA metrics target value (the threshold one), in some cases, I can see the scale-up works, but the other fails.

Provided my HPA:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa
  labels:
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
    - type: Pods
      pods:
        metric:
          name: plex_queue_size
        target:
          type: AverageValue
          averageValue: 2
  behavior:
    scaleUp:
      stabilizationWindowSeconds: 0
    scaleDown:
      stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300
```

When I set the target value to 2 in this case, I can see my HPA works perfectly ✅ , here is the logs:
You can see when my current value is 8, it was successfully scaled to 8/2 = 4 nodes ✅ ,:

```
$ kubectl get hpa -w
NAME                             REFERENCE                               TARGETS       MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa   Deployment/tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx   <unknown>/2   1         5         1          31s
tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa   Deployment/tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx   0/2           1         5         1          46s
tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa   Deployment/tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx   8/2           1         5         1          3m34s
tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa   Deployment/tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx   8/2           1         5         4          3m49s
tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa   Deployment/tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx   8/2           1         5         4          4m5s
tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa   Deployment/tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx   7666m/2       1         5         5          4m20s
tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa   Deployment/tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx   7666m/2       1         5         5          4m25s
```

However, now, if I update my HPA file, changing the target value to a larger one, say 5. (I delete the whole HPA and create a new one.)

```
metrics:
    - type: Pods
      pods:
        metric:
          name: plex_queue_size
        target:
          type: AverageValue
          averageValue: 5
```

From the log, you can see I can scrape the target number (0 in the beginning), but I after I have waited for a long time, there is NO scale-up behavior happens ❌ . The current value is scraped but no scale-up action happens ❌.
In my case, I should have 8/5, which is 2 desired replicas, however, nothing happens. ❌

This is what I have when I get the hpa and describe the HPA:

```
NAME                             REFERENCE                              TARGETS       MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa   Deployment/tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx   <unknown>/5   1         5         1          75s
tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa   Deployment/tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx   0/5           1         5         1          91s
tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa   Deployment/tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx   8/5           1         5         1          3m32s
tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa   Deployment/tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx   7/5           1         5         1          4m18s



kubectl describe horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa
Name:                        tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-hpa
Namespace:                    default
Labels:                       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:                  meta.helm.sh/release-name: tianbing
                              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
CreationTimestamp:            Wed, 10 Mar 2021 14:14:13 -0800
Reference:                    Deployment/tianbing-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx
Metrics:                      ( current / target )
  "plex_queue_size" on pods:  7 / 5
Min replicas:                 1
Max replicas:                 5
Deployment pods:              1 current / 1 desired
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason              Message
  ----            ------  ------              -------
  AbleToScale     True    ReadyForNewScale    recommended size matches current size
  ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound    the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from pods metric plex_queue_size
  ScalingLimited  False   DesiredWithinRange  the desired count is within the acceptable range
Events:
  Type     Reason                        Age                    From                       Message
  ----     ------                        ----                   ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetPodsMetric           6m10s (x5 over 7m12s)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metric plex_queue_size: unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: the server could not find the metric plex_queue_size for pods
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  6m10s (x5 over 7m12s)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  invalid metrics (1 invalid out of 1), first error is: failed to get pods metric value: unable to get metric plex_queue_size: unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: the server could not find the metric plex_queue_size for pods
```

Note: From the description, I saw some `Event` for `FailedGetPodsMetric` and `FailedComputeMetricsReplicas`, I believe that is just because the initial setup of HPA, since from HPA, I can scrape the metrics and also the `AbleToScale` and `ScalingActive` are also `True`.